# Binding to another element?

Tags: c#

I can't get this to work, I have a TextBlock that I want to bind its 'Text' property to a the Window's title.
I tried this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding path=Window.Title}" ... />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong syntax with binding. First add a name to your Window, let it be "window1".
Then do the following:

```
<TextBlock Text"{Binding ElementName=window1, Path=Title}" ... />
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
```

If the `Window` element has no name, you can refer to it with a `RelativeSource`.